# Running a java application in root domain and a wordpress blog in apache

Tags: apache-2.2, wordpress

I am running a play framework java application in a linode instance. My virtual host entry looks as follows.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ServerName www.example.com
 <Proxy *>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow From All
 </Proxy> 
 ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I want to install a wordpress blog and access it from www.example.com/blog. I have copied the wordpress folder to /var/www/blog. I am not able to access the URL www.example.com/blog as the request is going to the play framework. I would like to know how to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ProxyPass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) directive to *exempt* URLs from proxy processing like this:

```
ProxyPass /blog/ !
```

There are additional examples in the ProxyPass documentation.  So something like:

```
ProxyPass /blog/ !
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
```